# heatmap.2 (gplots package) - how to remove annoying lines in some cells?

Tags: r, heatmap, bioconductor

I'm trying to generate a simple heatmap that has each row and column
separated by a black line. However, for some reason this only happens
for the first and last color. The middle color in my `colorpanel()`
command has an addition horizontal and vertical line that I would like
to get rid off when plotted using `heatmap.2()`. Any suggestions as to why I see these lines?

```
library(gplots)

my.matrix <- cbind(func.1 = c(1,2,2,1,1,3,1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,1), func.2 =
c(2,2,1,1,3,3,1,1,2,2,1,3,3,2,1))

mycol <- colorpanel(n=3,"green","grey","red")

heatmap.2(my.matrix,Rowv=FALSE, Colv="Rowv", col=mycol, trace="both",
tracecol="black", key=FALSE, symm=FALSE, vline=NULL, hline=NULL)
```

link to the plot I get: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8900971/heatmap.png

Comment: heatmap.2() and colorpanel() are in the gplots package

Comment: @user1974415 what if use `trace="row"` and a line in the middle?

Comment: trace="row" does not solve the problem

Comment: @user1974415 Please use `?heatmap.2` and look this one up.  agstudy pointed you where to look but do some leg work on your own.

Comment: I did look it up... as well as trying the new code in R. But changing the trace argument in heatmap.2 to "row" still does not remove the horizontal line in the center of all grey cells. The part I don't understand is why only some colored cells have this horizontal line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a way to do what you want but when I read your last comment my mind went to ggplot2.  You didn't say it has to be a `heatmap.2` solution so here's a ggplot2 one.  Though I'm assuming the gplots version is of mor interest:

```
library(reshape2, ggplot2)
dat <- melt(my.matrix)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=Var2,y=Var1))+ 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour='black') +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("green","gray","red"),
    values  = rescale(c(min(dat$value), 1000, max(dat$value)))) +
    coord_equal()
```

Comment: no, heatmap.2 is not key. Many thanks for a very good alternative solution (which also motivates me to read more about ggplot2)